# Exchange online - move messages with powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I have a huge mailbox (~50Gb) with plenty of messages in 'Inbox' . I'm looking for moving certain messages received before particular date to another folder at the same mailbox.
I have tried to do it from Outlook Windows app but it seems too slow and I can't do it for all the messages at once. Outlook just crash.
Is there any way to perform the task from Exchange Powershell ? I can certainly create server side rule but how to apply it to the messages already in 'Inbox' ?

```
New-InboxRule -Name Testmove2018 -Mailbox test -MoveToFolder "MailboxName:\2018" -ReceivedAfterDate "09/01/2015"
```

Oleg

Comment: I would use either the EWS (Exchange Web Services) or the MS Graph API for actions like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exchange Online powershell module still allows you to copy and delete messages matching a search with `Search-Mailbox`, but you must copy them elsewhere first. Use an empty mailbox:

```
# First, check your search filter using EstimateOnly or LogOnly:
Search-Mailbox myUser@domain.com -SearchQuery 'Subject:Move Me' -EstimateResultOnly

# Copy the items to a temp mailbox and delete from the primary
# (EXO does not allow copying search results to same mailbox)
# param block just for readability:
$Params = @{
  Identity      = 'myUser@domain.com' 
  SearchQuery   = 'Subject:Move Me' 
  TargetMailbox = 'temp@domain.com' 
  TargetFolder  = 'Temp' 
  DeleteContent = $true
}
$TempResult = Search-Mailbox @Params

# Now move back to original mailbox
$Params.Identity      = 'temp@domain.com'
$Params.TargetMailbox = 'myUser@domain.com'
$Params.TargetFolder  = 'Moved'
$MoveResult = Search-Mailbox @Params
```

Then just make sure the number of emails is equal. EXO can take a while to get synced up, so if it's not finding all the email to move back, just give it a while and run the second search again:

```
If ($TempResult.ResultItemsCount -eq $MoveResult.ResultItemsCount) {
  "We're good!"
} Else { 
  Write-Warning "Move results not equal!"
  $TempResult
  $MoveResult
}
```

Note that this is the 'Old' method, which is already retired and may be removed in the future. The new method is supposed to be using the `New-ComplianceSearch` style commands, but they have some limitations and aren't built for this purpose.

In my opinion, the "easiest" way is to open the mailbox in the browser > search for what you want > scroll down to load all the messages if needed > select all > move to > "move to a different folder..."

Comment: With 'Select All' , Move option is not available. I believe this is known issue. However with OWA it is much faster than with Outlook 365 to move mails by 1000-1500 items in a row.